# ElasticSearch scripting set an object value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to use a script to set several values of my Elastic document.

```
POST myindex/_update_by_query
{
   "script" : {
      "source": """
        ctx._source.categories='categories';
        ctx._source.myObject={};
        """,
      "lang": "painless"  
    },
    "query": {
        "term" : {
            "name": "Tony"
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't set an object value with this painless language. However I write it, I get an error.
Is there a way to do this, maybe with a different script language ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create an object (i.e. a hash map), you should do it this way:

```
    ctx._source.myObject = [:];
```